# Wordpress site structure and adding subpage

Tags: php, wordpress

i need to edit a Wordpress based site, but i am new in Wordpress and php. Let's say, there is a site myhomesite_com, it has some subpages, like myhomesite_com/about, myhomesite_com/forum and so on. What is the files and folders structure of Wordpress site ? How do i create a new subpage (i.e., myhomesite_com/news) and edit it ?

Comment: Go through the following article : https://codex.wordpress.org/Pages

Comment: If you tried googling you wouldn't have to ask this question. Head over to  https://codex.wordpress.org/Pages#To_create_a_subpage, its all described in the `To create a subpage` section

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a working worpdress theme, you do not have to code your subpages. To add new subpages you need to create them on the dashboard. No code skills required here at all.

```
1) Go to myhomesite_com/wp-admin
2) Go to Pages -> Add New and create your page.
```

If everything is setup correctly, the page should be up.

Comment: Thanks, thats what i was looking for, i tried looking in wordpress manual, but they dont know themselves how to open admin panel :)